# Windows defender ransomware protection and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2019, windows-defender, ransomware

Our small company has organized several levels of virus protection for Windows servers, but there are always fears that this is not enough.

Is it correct to configure Windows Defender Ransomware Proteсtion to directories with data and transaction log of the SQL server?
Will this have a noticeable effect on performance?

Comment: Controlled Folder Access is not supported on Windows Server 2012. Is there a reason you added that tag?

Comment: @GregAskew sorry, that was a mistake. We have Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender is malware protection that helps identify and remove viruses, spyware, and other malicious software. All antivirus antimalware software should exclude from its activity SQL Server related files, directories and processes. Please read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-choose-antivirus-software-to-run-on-computers-that-are-running-sql-server-feda079b-3e24-186b-945a-3051f6f3a95b)** all the exclusions you have to configure for Windows Defender and the reason behind those exclusions.